# Can you run ExUnit tests in an environment other than "test"

Tags: unit-testing, elixir

When you run ExUnit tests, they usually run in the "test" environment (Mix.env="test"). Is there a way to have them run in a different environment, like "unittest"? I'd like to use "test" for configuring our QA testing environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the MIX_ENV variable?

```
$ MIX_ENV=yourenv mix test
```

Comment: Does this work for you? I get errors when I try this with MIX_ENV set to anything other than "test".

Comment: Yep. Tried with a pet project here and worked. It only complained that the prod env wasn't compiled before (fixed with MIX_ENV=prod mix compile)

Comment: Ok, this got it. It wasn't compiling Phoenix's conn_case.ex. So I had to edit elixirc_paths() in mix.exs so that :unittest looked the same as :test.